# create a stop watch falls with error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a stop watch which works good but in sec value after 60 sec i need the timer to go to zero and min to 1, And in the same way for every 60 sec min should change

```
    /* Stopwatch */
    starttime(){
        console.log("timer started");
        if( this.running == 0){
            this.running = 1;
            this.adder()
        }else{
            this.running = 0;
        }
   }

    reset(){
        console.log("timer reset");
        this.running = 0;
        this.time = 0;
        this.total = 0;
        this.Sec = 0;

    }

    adder(){

        console.log("timer incrementor");
        if(this.running == 1){
            setTimeout(()=>{ 
                this.time++;
                var mins = Math.floor(this.time/10/60);
                var sec = Math.floor(this.time / 10 );
                var tens = this.time/10;

                this.total =  mins + ':' +  sec;
                console.log(this.total) ;
                this.Sec = sec;               
                this.adder()  

            },10)
        }

    }
```

But here time changes, sec gets added up it does not goes to zero when it reaches 60 it moves on to 61,62,63.... sample time after 120 secs is 0:2:120, What i need is 0:2:0 (hrs:sec:min)

worked fine after modifying ' var sec = Math.floor(this.time / 10)%60;' and changed set time  out time to

```
this.adder()  

                },100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your calculation for second is wrong. use following statement instead of yours.

```
var sec = Math.floor(this.time / 10)%60;
```

Comment: ya this worked but i feel my timer is working to fast i compared my timer with stopwatch in my mobile, when mytimer is at 20 sec mobile timer is at 15se

Comment: i changed the set timeout time to 100 first it was in 10 worked fine thank you for your ans %60

Comment: Could u tell me how could i bring this state 00:00 to my timer any suggestion @reza

Comment: When you are resetting your timer that time if you print with same logic, it will show 00:00

Comment: no initially timer is in 0:0, it should start like this 01:01, 1min & 1sec

Comment: then when resetting your time, put this.time = 610;

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the option, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format the elapsed time.

```
this.total = moment.utc(this.time).format("mm:ss.SSS"))
```

Otherwise ignore this answer ;)